# using canvas in love2d results in out-of-memory error

Tags: canvas, resize, out-of-memory, ram, love2d

I'm currently writing a game (for learning purposes) in lua with love2d and today i wanted to make my window size resizable.
I didn't want to resize every graphical object separately, so i searched the web and found a recommendation to use canvases in this case. (draw everything on a canvas; resize it; draw it)

Without using canvas, my program uses 252,8mb ram, but as soon as i use canvas, the used memory gets more and more until the program crashes. And since i'm relatively new to lua and new to love2d, i'm not able to pinpoint and get rid of the problem i have in my code.

My code (with canvas):

I have a global variable `canvas` which (in my `resources.lua`) is set to:

> canvas = love.graphics.newCanvas(STANDARD_SETTINGS.display.width,STANDARD_SETTINGS.display.height)

(width equals 1280p and height 720p)
and in my `main.lua`, i have this code in the `draw()` function:

```
function love.draw()
    canvas:renderTo(function()
        gameStates[activeState].draw()
    end)
    canvasImageData = canvas:getImageData()
    canvas:clear()
    if canvasImage == nil then
        canvasImage = love.graphics.newImage(canvasImageData)
    else
        canvasImage:refresh()
    end
    canvasImage:setFilter("linear","nearest")
    love.graphics.setColor(255, 255, 255, 255)
    love.graphics.draw(canvasImage,0,0,0,settings.display.factor,settings.display.factor)
end
```

Without the canvas, my code looks like this:

```
function love.draw()
    gameStates[activeState].draw()
end
```

(The table `gameStates[activeState]` returns for example the `mainMenu`-table with a draw function in it that is called)

By the way, the resizing works fine with the canvas until the ram is full and the program crashes.

Help would really be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can just draw the canvas. Not sure what you're using the image for, but it's not necessary.

```
local canvas = love.graphics.newCanvas()
local settings = { display = { factor = 0.7 } }

function mydraw()
    -- draw something as an example
    love.graphics.print("Something", 10, 10)
end

function love.draw()
    canvas:clear()
    canvas:renderTo(mydraw)
    love.graphics.setColor(255, 255, 255, 255)
    canvas:setFilter("linear", "nearest")
    love.graphics.draw(canvas,0,0,0,settings.display.factor,settings.display.factor)
end
```

You seem to be running into this issue: https://bitbucket.org/rude/love/issues/590/memory-leak-with-canvas-getimagedata

Comment: i have to update (clear and re-fill the canvas) my canvas content each time love.draw is called, but your code works perfectly for that ,too, thx.
I only have to place `canvas:renderTo(mydraw)` into the `draw` function instead of `load` and have to call `canvas:clear` one line above it.
no memory problem with this. =)

Comment: @frosty You're right, I made it as a simple example of drawing a canvas, but I've edited the answer to do it the way you needed.

Answer (score 0):

I found the source of the problem, even though i'm not certain why, and i found a work-around for the problem (just in case someone has similar problems):
The memory problem was caused by the function `love.graphics.newImage(canvasImageData)` and also the methods `canvasImage:refresh()` and `canvas:getImageData()` which all three caused the out-of-memory problem.

My workaround:
I found the function `love.graphics.scale(sx,sy)` in the [love wiki](https://www.love2d.org/wiki/love.graphics.scale) and used it to get rid of the whole canvas code problem.
My `draw()`function now looks like this:

```
function love.draw()
    love.graphics.scale(settings.display.factor, settings.display.factor)
    gameStates[activeState].draw()
end
```

By the way for the sake of completeness:
When i resize my window content, i also change the window size with this in another function `love.window.setMode(settings.display.width,settings.display.height)`